# Is Refactoring with different class casting and property calling possible ?

Tags: c#

Can i refactor these code ?

The diffrent between these block of code are.

1. They are using different casting type.
2. They call different property

   ```
       var objBillOfMaterialRow = (MISheetDataSet.BillOfMaterialRow)pObjDataset.Tables["BillOfMaterial"].Rows[0];
       if (objBillOfMaterialRow.mi1_BillOfMaterial == ShowReport.False)
       {
           pObjDataset.Tables["BillOfMaterial"].Clear();
       }

       var objLayerBuildUpRow= (MISheetDataSet.LayerRow)pObjDataset.Tables["LayerBuildUp"].Rows[0];
       if (objLayerBuildUpRow.mi1_LayerBuildUp == ShowReport.False)
       {
           pObjDataset.Tables["LayerBuildUp"].Clear();
       }

       var objConstructionRow = (MISheetDataSet.ConstructionRow)pObjDataset.Tables["Construction"].Rows[0];
       if (objConstructionRow.mi2_Construction == ShowReport.False)
       {
           pObjDataset.Tables["Construction"].Clear();
       }
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work if you don't want to change anything in your classes:

```
var rows = new Dictionary<string, Func<DataRow, ShowReport>>
       {
          {"BillOfMaterial", dr => ((MISheetDataSet.BillOfMaterialRow)dr).mi1_BillOfMaterial},
          {"LayerBuildUp", dr => ((MISheetDataSet.LayerRow)dr).mi1_LayerBuildUp},
          {"Construction", dr => ((MISheetDataSet.ConstructionRow)dr).mi2_Construction},
       };

foreach (var row in rows)
{
    var dataRow = pObjDataset.Tables[row.Key].Rows[0];
    var showReportExtractor = row.Value;
    var showReport = showReportExtractor(dataRow);
    if (showReport == ShowReport.False)
        pObjDataset.Tables[row.Key].Clear();
}
```

(Don't forget to give meaningful names to variables)

But I would consider refactoring classes to allow more straightforward extraction of these `mi1_BillOfMaterial`, `mi1_LayerBuildUp`, `mi2_Construction` members. You have three classes here, each of them has `ShowReport` property but with different name. The idea is to extract a base class which will have this property, in this case we won't need to know the exact type of the row:

```
public abstract class RowBase
{
    public abstract ShowReport ShowReport { get; }
}

public class BillOfMaterialRow : RowBase
{
    public override ShowReport ShowReport { get { return mi1_BillOfMaterial; } }
}

// Two other classes implemented in the same way
```

And then your method will be as simple as:

```
var rows = new []
       {
          "BillOfMaterial",
          "LayerBuildUp",
          "Construction", 
       };

foreach (var tableName in rows)
{
    var row = (RowBase)pObjDataset.Tables[tableName].Rows[0];
    if (row.ShowReport == ShowReport.False)
        pObjDataset.Tables[tableName].Clear();
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Snowbear, This is the first time i've seen this technique. I am excited to try it right now :D

Comment: Thank you it works :)
What is your idea about refactoring classes to allow more straightforward extraction of these please, i would like to know more about it ?

Comment: @Sarawut, expanded answer

Comment: JIM-compiler - Thanks, I will try if Dataset can do that or not :D